# How to found the problem of crash log in Iphone

Tags: iphone

```
       I am new one to develop iphone App. so help me to found out error in crash log. In crash log contains only library or framework. Help me to found out crash line .Thanks in advance.
```

Regards,

Arunkumar.P

Answer (score 1):

Run in debug mode and hit Command + Shift + R or Run -> Console.  Also put in `NSLog@"%@", class);` replace class with what you suspect is causing an issue.  For integers, use `%d`.

Comment: How to found in device crash Log .

Comment: Window -> Organizer -> Choose your device in left hand column -> Crash Logs -> Choose your app.

Answer (score 0):

Display the console in XCode (Run -> Console) to see the log

Rq: Remove space before your line to not display like code

Comment: How to found in device crash Log